# Creating concentric circles in a picture

Tags: python

I am attempting to overlay 2 concentric circles (with different radii) over a picture.  The problem I am encountering is that, after the first circle, the following circles don't show up.  I assumed the algorithm would perform the functions in the order they're written which would overlay the white circle over the red one however it doesn't.  The X and Y values are set up so that regardless of the dimensions of the picture, the outer circle would touch the edges of the longer side.

```
def concentricCircles(pic):
  X = getWidth(pic)
  Y = getHeight(pic)
  if(X >= Y):
    addOvalFilled(pic,(X/2) - (Y/2),0, Y, Y, green)    
  if(X < Y):
    addOvalFilled(pic, 0 , (Y/2) - (X/2), X, X, green)
  if(X >= Y):
    addOvalFilled(pic,((X/2) - (Y/3)),0+(Y/6), 2/3*Y, 2/3*Y, blue)
  if(X < Y):
    addOvalFilled(pic,((Y/2) - (X/3)),0+(X/6), 2/3*X, 2/3*X, blue)
  show(pic)
```

Do I have to establish a for loop within the if statement to perform what I'm looking for?  Can I embed an if statement within another or combine the addOvalFilled functions within the same if statement?  Would it be more feasible to copy the image onto a canvas before applying the concentric circles?  If so how would I go about doing that in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: What library do you actually use to paint the circles? Do you manage to paint at least one circle?

Comment: Yes I get the first big circle however the next circle (2/3 the size of the first one) doesn't appear.

Comment: what happens if you cast to an `int` first?

Comment: Are you referring to integers?  Since I'm referencing pixels here I don't think changing the values to integers will be effective.

Comment: well jython is a mix of python with Java and the java version only seems to work with int's. And there is no problem with trying?

Comment: I tried however it didn't work.  The response was: The error was: 2nd arg can't be coerced to int
Inappropriate argument type.
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.

Comment: yes, but this is rather weird. One would expect `X` and `Y` to be numbers... Don't you?

Comment: Yes X and Y are numerical representations of the width and height of the picture (respectively.)  The issue isn't the fact that they're not being recognized as numbers, the issue is that after the first oval appears, no further ovals appear overtop of it to produce concentric circles (in this case.)